# Python Syntaxerror: invalid

Tags: python, powershell

I have been trying for the past two hours to understand what I'm doing wrong. I am just starting off in Python and I can't wrap my head around a few basic things.

I am using:
 * Python 2.7.8
 * Windows Powershell

This is my error:

```
>>> python ex1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python ex1
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

One thing to note, I've noticed if I force Python to start through a file, it unexpectedly closes. Could this be an administration issue?

I do not know how to do a traceback, or when I try it in Powershell, it gives me an error.

I fixed my silly error:  I was using using Python in Powershell, instead of just using the command line. I also made an error in notepad++ - I accidentally had 2 spaces in Line 1 and 2 that I didn't catch.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: EX1 is the file i've created using notepad++

I am trying to run python by running what I have written in notepad ++

           ^

Comment: Run `python ex1` from Powershell directly. Don't open up a Python session and then try to run `python ex1` from there.

Comment: @user2357122

i get 
PS C:\Users\$\project> python ex1.py.
  File "ex1.py.", line 1
    print "Hello World!"
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
PS C:\Users\$\project>

Comment: @Pcurry Hi, May I ask why the edit was needed? Some of these just seem to be personal things you dont like, rather than grammatical?

Comment: @Invention I capitalize the proper nouns in questions and answers, which I believe is correct grammar, as well as being more readable to me.  Capitalizing 'I' is correct grammar, and so I fixed that.  The rest of the layout changes I thought made it easier to read, and clearer what you were saying.  If I have offended in my changes, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to run `ex1.py` from python shell I think,

Because `>>>` is prompt for python shell. Please try to do that from command prompt.

I got same error when I tried from python shell.

```
root@localhost $ python
pythPython 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python ex1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python ex1
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Please try

```
root@localhost $ python ex1.py
```

Comment: Hi! I continue to get the same error. 

I am trying it in Windows powershell

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> root@localhost $ python ex1.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    root@localhost $ python ex1.py
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: what is content in `ex1.py`?

Comment: maybe this will help, http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex1.html

This is where i'm getting it from. I am using this as a tutorial

Comment: Never mind! I found my error! I am a silly string of issues! I apologize. while trying to fix my error, I made a few others as well. in PowerShell I turned python on, instead of simply doing it in the command line    and in notepad I accidentally put an space in line 1 and 2.  that took 2 hours just for something as simple as that! Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try executing the file in cmd and not in REPL

I was getting the same error but now I tried doing the same on cmd it worked for me!

```
>>> notepad mybasic.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    notepad mybasic.py
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do not go inside REPL by typing python + enter rather than work on cmd.

```
C:\Users\Neha\IIEC_python>notepad mybasics.py

C:\Users\Neha\IIEC_python>python mybasics.py
Hii Neha
```